# What offerings are best for rahu and ketu?

Tags: puja, navagraha, shani, rahu, ketu

I am currently doing a 21 day fast for Rahu and Ketu to remove bad energy from me, what are the best offerings?

Comment: Horse gram is usually offered for Ketu  and Black orid dal for Rahu . You may check if  this matches with your customs.